# Callback URL changes to localhost even though the hostname is changed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So, I have installed WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0, as a Windows service, on a server and ran into no problems accessing it from there. After that, I, then, tried to access it from another computer. The management console (/carbon) seemed to work just fine. But, when it comes to the other pages (/publisher and /devportal), it would work, is what it would seem like at first, but when it loads the login call back url, that's when it goes back to using localhost, which, obviously, will result in it not being able to load. So far, I have tried the things I found on the internet, but nothing worked so far, I even did a reinstall and just used the `deployment.toml` file as it is the only config file needed as per the documentation. Through there, I changed the hostname accordingly as it seemed to be the likely fix based on what I was able to find. After doing so, a different problem occurs, it says that it is currently unable to handle the request, and it's shown to be as "HTTP ERROR 500".

I'm pretty clueless as to what to do now, and, admittedly, I'm having difficulties on further understanding the technicalities that this entails as it is not my area of expertise. In any case, what would be the best course of action with regards to this kind of issue? Thanks in advance.

Note (just in case that it might be needed/useful): When it loads the call back url and eventually redirects to localhost, changing localhost back to the hostname, and then reloading the page works. And if it does that again, which it does at every chance it gets, I just change it again then reload.

Answer (score 0):

APIM portals used authorization code grant to authenticate users. Once the user login is successful, the user will be redirected back to the given callback URL. The callback URL is basically where your portals/web app are hosted.

Callback URLs are derived from the hostname and proxy port at startup referring to `deployment.toml`. If the URLs are different(In case LB and not localhost), either you have to define then in the `deployment.toml` before the start or change the callback URL of the portal applications.

You can change the callback URL of a portal by login to the management console(/carbon) and editing the correct service provider of the portal application.